# Подключить к PHP-скрипту фрагмент кода, написанный на Python

Tags: python, php

а возможно ли подключить к PHP-скрипту фрагмент кода, написанный на Python ?

Answer (score 2):

[system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php):

> system — Execute an external program and display the output

Например:

```
$last = system('python script.py args', $retval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас возник такой странный вопрос - меняйте подход к решению задачи.
Пишите сразу либо на PHP, либо на Python.

Comment: У меня например возникла сейчас такая задача, к большому проекту на php подключить другой внушительный проект на python, ну не переписывать же один из них - приходиться использовать то что посоветовал @John Brown@